# Return Java JsonPath as a json string

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Using the java json path library: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Given a json like this

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference"
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction"
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

I would like to return "book" as a list of strings. For examples:

```
List<String> results = JsonPath.read(example, "$.store.book[*]");
```

And results should look like:

```
["{\"category\":\"reference\"}", "{\"category\":\"fiction\"}"]
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Currently:

```
System.out.println(udf.jsonExtractScalar(testExample, "$.store.book[*]").getClass().getName());
--> net.minidev.json.JSONArray
```

Comment: What's the problem? `JSONArray` is a subtype of `List`, and in this case happens to contain Strings.

Comment: As book is a JsonArray in you json tree, you can JsonArray tupe and retrieve the data from it and add it the list.

Answer (score 0):

As book is a JsonArray in you json tree, you can use JsonArray type and retrieve the data from it and add  to the list.

Here is an example.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayString);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
list.add( jsonArray.getString(i) );
```

Replace jsonArrayString with you jsondata's books array name and you will be good to go.

The class used will be JSONArray class which is

```
 `org.json.JSONArray`
```

Comment: Which `JSONArray` class is that?

Comment: It would be androids own class.

Comment: Please add that to your answer and explain why they should use that over what they already have, ie. Jayway's `JsonPath` with `net.minidev.json.JSONArray`.

Comment: It is `org.json.JSONArray` .When there are already classes available in android then why to use the third part library?  If android classes are not fullfilling your needs then its ok to use another library to meet your requirements.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Would you be able to suggest a non android solution?

Comment: @samol `org.json` is available outside of Android.

Comment: Yes it is java library.can be used outside android too.